# How to override form id of Webform in drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to override form_id of webform in drupal7. Example webform form id is "webform_141" and I want to override it to "webform_en" or "webform_uk". Is it possible in Drupal7?

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 3):

if is an existing form use a hook_form_alter :

```
MYMODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
   if($form_id == 'webform_141'){
     $form['#attributes'] = array('id' => "webform_en"); // or webform_uk
   }
}
```

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x